# How to reset h2 database between fitnesse tests?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, fitnesse

I want to reset the database (H2) between fitnesse pages.

My best guess for now is to drop and recreate the base in the setup.

I tried with `SchemaExport`, but it uses a .sql file and my DB configuration is with JPA Annotations.

If i `"DROP ALL OBJECTS"` or even `"SHUTDOWN"`, i don't know how to recreate the tables

I could use `"TRUNCATE TABLE"` but it's not generic and i think it will be even longer than droping and recreating.

I can't rollback a transaction because the fixtures don't share the same transaction.

`Hbm2ddl=create-drop` won't work because i load the spring context only once for the entire test suite.

How do you, fitnesse/spring/hibernate user, handle this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

This might not end up being my only answer, but at the moment I can talk about how I did something like this in the past.

One option, and I agree it is much more cumbersome than what you are looking for, is to run the test suites as separate entities in your CI system.  What I've done in the past is rather than run our entire test suite as one big run, is broken it out into separate Hudson/Jenkins jobs (this improved our ability to run tests quickly and reduced memory issues). Then as a part of the launching of the hudson/jenkins job we reset the database.

Doing it this way you wind up with more hudson/jenkins jobs, but if you can run suites against separate databases, you can potentially run more than one job in parallel.